# mysqldump problem in Crontab and bash file

Tags: linux, bash, cron, mysql-backup

I have created a cron tab to backup my DB each 30 minutes...

```
*/30 * * * * bash /opt/mysqlbackup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The cron tab works well.. Each 30 minutes I have my backup with the script bellow.

```
#!/bin/sh
find /opt/mysqlbackup -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} +
mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --user=myuser -- 
password=mypass mydb | gzip -9 > /opt/mysqlbackup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M)_mydb.sql.gz
```

But my problem is that the rm function to delete old data isn't working.. this is never deleted.. Do you know why ?

and also... the name of my backup is 2020-02-02-12.12_mydb.sql.gz?

I always have a ? at the end of my file name.. Do you know why ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What does `find /opt/mysqlbackup -type f -mtime +2` output? How about if you invoke it via cron e.g. `find /opt/mysqlbackup -type f -mtime +2 > /tmp/cronoutput` does it differ?

Comment: if I execute `find /opt/mysqlbackup -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} +` in the terminal... Everything works well

Comment: Yes but that's in your shell and not what cron is doing. Show us the output of the command (without the rm) which cron is seeing.

Comment: Better to stick to full paths in crontabs. `bash` → `/bin/bash`. However, if you say the rest of the script runs OK, this cannot be the solution...

Comment: The output of the cron you tell me give me exactly what I expected

Comment: this is not linked to `bash → /bin/bash` because the script is actually running

Comment: There's a real possibility the user you're running cron from might not have permissions to rm / ls from that directory - as a starting point.

Comment: So find with option -delete could work? How to know which user run the cron?

Comment: @Chatis How did you create the cron definition? Did you add it to the system-level crontab, e.g. `/etc/crontab`? Or did you use a user-level crontab file, e.g. editing the contents of `crontab -u <someuser> -e`?

Answer (score 0):

The question mark typically indicates a character that can't be displayed; the fact that it's at the end of a line makes me think that your script has Windows line endings rather than Unix. You can fix that with the `dos2unix` command:
`dos2unix /path/to/script.sh`

It's also good practice not to throw around MySQL passwords on the CLI or store them in executable scripts. You can accomplish this by using [MySQL Option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html), specifically the file that defines user-level options (`~/.my.cnf`).

This would require us to figure out which user is executing that cronjob, however. My assumption is that you did not make that definition inside the system-level crontab; if you had, you'd actually be trying to execute `/opt/mysqlbackup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` as the user `bash`. This user most likely doesn't (and shouldn't) exist, so cron would fail to execute the script entirely.

As this is not the case (you say it's executing the mysqldump just fine), this makes me believe you have the definition in a user-level crontab instead. Once we figure out which user that actually is as I asked for in my comment, we can identify the file permissions issue as well as create the aforementioned MySQL options file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` with `mtime` is not the best choice. If for some reason mysqldump stops creating backups, then in two days all backups will be deleted.

You can use my Python script "rotate-archives" for smart delete backups. (https://gitlab.com/k11a/rotate-archives). The script adds the current date at the beginning of the file or directory name. Like 2020-12-31_filename.ext. Subsequently uses this date to decide on deletion.

Running a script on your question:

```
rotate-archives.py test_mode=off age_from-period-amount_for_last_timeslot=0-0-48 archives_dir=/mnt/archives
```

In this case, 48 new archives will always be saved. Old archives in excess of this number will be deleted.

An example of more flexible archives deletion:

```
rotate-archives.py test_mode=off age_from-period-amount_for_last_timeslot=7-5,31-14,365-180-5 archives_dir=/mnt/archives
```

As a result, there will remain archives from 7 to 30 days old with a time interval between archives of 5 days, from 31 to 364 days old with time interval between archives 14 days, from 365 days old with time interval between archives 180 days and the number of 5.